# Unity: How to move object in direction camera is facing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity and trying to move my player object in a direction relative to where the camera is facing. The camera is currently able to rotate/orbit around the player object by using the mouse, however, it only moves in directions relative to the world, not the camera. In essence, I'm trying to replicate what the game Absolver does. There's a good clip in this youtube video at around 4:30 showing the camera/player movement: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lBqCTeJwYw&t=1199s.

I've looked at youtube videos, unity answers and scripting manuals dealing with joysticks, quaternions, and Euler values, but I just can't seem to find a solution that fits my particular problem. Any help would be absolutely great. Thanks in advance!

Camera Rotation Code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const float Y_ANGLE_MIN = 0f;
    private const float Y_ANGLE_MAX = 85f;

    public Transform lookAt;
    public Transform camTransform;

    private Camera cam;

    private float distance = 10f;
    private float currentX = 0f;
    private float currentY = 0f;
    private float sensitivityX = 5f;
    private float sensitivityY = 5f;

    private void Start()
    {
        camTransform = transform;
        cam = Camera.main;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        currentX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX;
        currentY -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;

        currentY = Mathf.Clamp(currentY, Y_ANGLE_MIN, Y_ANGLE_MAX);
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 dir = new Vector3(0, 0, -distance);
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(currentY, currentX, 0);
        camTransform.position = lookAt.position + rotation * dir;
        camTransform.LookAt(lookAt.position);
    }
}
```

Player Movement Code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Rigidbody rb;
    public Camera cam;

    public float movementForce = 500f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, 0, movementForce * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(-movementForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("s"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, 0, -movementForce * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(movementForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if (rb.position.y < -1f)
        {
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the `transform.forward` property of your camera.

Something like this:

```
rb.AddForce(cam.transform.forward * movementForce * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
```

You also have at your disposal:

```
transform.left
transform.right
```

There is an example of exactly this on the [AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) docs.